# How to work with two different APIs with React?

Tags: reactjs, proxy, create-react-app, package.json

I need to test one endpoint inside an API, but I already work with one API, and I wouldn't like to change all my calls targeting just the new API.

I don't know event if it's possible, but is there some way to define more than one `proxy` inside `package.json`?

Is there some way to pass auth keys inside `package.json`?

The main server, is a local server, with a proxy:

```
"proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3001/proxy",
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      }
    }
  },
```

Currently I'm using `axios` to make API calls, and the project was started with `create-react-app`.

Comment: Yes, according to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1790) `create-react-app` should be able to handle multiple proxies in the package.json. Have you tried to add a second proxy? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I added after the first one, and it worked! (I didn't thought it was so easy, I would think if the proxy would be an array). How about passing headers inside `package.json`?

Comment: Hmm, I know that [webpack-dev-server supports this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-headers-), but I'm not sure if `create-react-app` will honor it. I would try adding the `headers` key to your `package.json` and see if that works. If not, I would suggest setting up an [axios interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) that adds them on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution adding the second proxy after the first one, inside the `proxy` and it was not necessary for me too put headers inside `package.json`, but the links shared by @Chase DeAnda are really interesting, and can help who is interested:
[Webpack headers](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-headers-) and [axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors).

Comment: Can you give an example? I have tried what @avijeet suggested, it works partially. I can make request to both api2 and api1, but it stops to proxy other urls. For example, when I enter localhost:3000/customer, I expect that it should behave as it was, but it gives a 404 error.   I use following conf: `"proxy": {
    "/api2": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8081/"
    },
    "/.*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/"
    }
  }`

Answer (score 5):

In package.json, you can configure the proxy server to make API requests to different targets based on maching the pattern for different API requests in the way it is shown as follows.

Things to note:

- Order of the API patterns matters, the generic request(*) must be last.
- The regex should be such that it matches the complete url, a partial match resulted in errors for me.

The following piece of code worked for me. There are 3 different servers, one for the reports request, one for the access control request, and rest all requests should go to the third server.

```
"proxy": {
    "/report/.*(_get)": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8093/"
    },
    "/access/.*(_get)": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8091/"
    },
    "/.*": {
      "target": "https://egov-micro-dev.egovernments.org/",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  },
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome example, the will `_get` enable just `get` requests for the urls with this pattern? or is this a pattern of the path in url?

Comment: This is a pattern of the path in the url. I don't think you can explicitly separate GET & POST requests.

Comment: When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string. Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".

Comment: An object for proxy is no longer supported. See: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5103